Google Analytics API Error - Gapic::UniverseDomainMismatch
I have been using the Google Analytics API (google-analytics-data, version: 1.4) in my Ruby on Rails app for the past 3 years and it has been working great up until 9/25/24 when all the queries started failing with a confusing error
Error Class: Gapic::UniverseDomainMismatch
Error Message: Universe domain is googleapis.com but credentials are in
This is the problematic code:
def get_auth
  client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("CREDENTIAL_FILE_PATH.json")
  auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
end

client = Google::Analytics::Data::V1beta::AnalyticsData::Client.new do |config|
  config.credentials = get_auth
end

This is the backtrace from the error:
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/gapic-common-0.21.1/lib/gapic/universe_domain_concerns.rb:68:in 'setup_universe_domain'
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/gapic-common-0.21.1/lib/gapic/grpc/service_stub.rb:78:in 'initialize'
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/google-analytics-data-v1beta-0.2.0/lib/google/analytics/data/v1beta/analytics_data/client.rb:157:in 'new'
/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/google-analytics-data-v1beta-0.2.0/lib/google/analytics/data/v1beta/analytics_data/client.rb:157:in 'initialize'
get_ga4_data.rb:7:in 'new'

I have tried various things like updating to a newer version of the gem but that introduced new seemingly unrelated errors. The Google documentation is very difficult for me to understand but I was unable to find any breaking changes that could have caused this. I was also unable to find any documentation regarding this error.
The only thing I can think of is that I recently updated my google ads gem, so maybe there is a shared dependency issue.
Does anybody know the nature of this error and if there is anything else I can try?

Just needed to manually add the universe_domain.
def get_auth
    client_secrets = Google::APIClient::ClientSecrets.load("CREDENTIAL_FILE_PATH.json")
    auth_client = client_secrets.to_authorization
    auth_client.universe_domain = "googleapis.com"
    auth_client
end

The error was really not useful at all.
